# update dart sdk for flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sdk

I would like to use dart SDK >= 2.2.0 with flutter. But my current version used BY Flutter is 2.1.2

```
flutter --version
Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (2 months ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

I tried to install the 2.2.0 version independently and I succeed :

```
dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.2.0 (Tue Feb 26 15:04:32 2019 +0100) on "macos_x64"
```

However, Flutter doesn't use this version as you can see above. I tried to replace files of the `dart-sdk` used by flutter (`flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`) by the version that I installed independently, but when I try to run Flutter after that I have a snapshot problem so I have put back the original `dart-sdk` folder in the flutter directory.

Do you have any ideas how can I update it?

PS: I downloaded flutter very recently (10 days ago) from here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It might be due to the fact you are on `channel stable` which is the most secure builds of the four channels to get updated (channels are listed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels))

If you are a bit more curious to try out the new features without having to risk bad builds I advocate `channel beta`:

> Every month, we pick the "best" dev build of the previous month or so, and promote it to beta. These builds have been tested with our codelabs.

where the stable channel has this description:

> When we believe we have a particularly good build, we promote it to the stable channel. We intend to do this more or less every quarter, but this may vary. We recommend that you use this channel for all production app releases. We may ship hotfixes to the stable channel for high-priority bugs, although our intent is to do this rarely.

You can change the channel to point at `beta` by running this command in your terminal: 
`flutter channel beta` followed by `flutter upgrade` to ensure you have got the last release for this particular branch.

Let me know how this affect your situation.

Comment: It totally helped. Now my flutter dart version is 2.3.0! Thank you :)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that Flutter includes the Dart SDK and not to install them separately.

Comment: thanks for sharing, searching for this issue for a long time.

Comment: But can we actually update the Dart SDK version and keep the current Flutter version? I have a situation where this has become a necessity.

Comment: @cVergel, just to clarify; you want to run with a never release of the Dart SDK without upgrading the Flutter version? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100021/3266152) trick will allow you to utilize a newer Dart SDK. You must upgrade your Dart version, however.

Comment: i changed it it works but found in dart many types it stable or beta or dev

Answer (score 88):

You have to upgrade flutter from cli with `flutter upgrade` command. Then flutter will use latest version of Dart SDK. Flutter does not use your local Dart Sdk.

Comment: Can you make flutter use your local Dart sdk?

Answer (score 70):

This issue is because of the dart version and by updating flutter the dart version won't update,
the way for solving this is,
first, you need to be on the dev or master channel,

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

after that run `flutter doctor -v` as you see your dart is still an old one

in this step, you should update it manually, as the doc says [Dart](https://dart.dev/get-dart)

for Windows user

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

for Mac users
if you user brew to install dart

```
brew upgrade dart
```

and if you don't, you can install it

```
 brew tap dart-lang/dart
 brew install dart
```

wish this solves your issue.

Comment: this could not install the dart 2.17 and 2.18. @Ali Azimoshan is it possible to upgrade in macos?

Answer (score 11):

You might need to **Update your pubspec.yaml** depending on the flutter channel you want to work on:

If you are on stable channel :

Go into pubspec.yaml and type in:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"
```

(**Whatever Dart SDK version** you want comes in the front)

```
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
```

If you are on beta channel :

```
environment:
      sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
```

Then if you are on stable channel (or beta), open the terminal in your IDE and enter

```
flutter channel stable
# or flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
```

Check the version with **flutter --version**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

it is so simple if dart was installed with flutter just do the below line:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 8):

Run `flutter upgrade` on your Terminal and it will automatically update the dart SDK and flutter version

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade dart SDK using terminal by typing `flutter upgrade`.
This will upgrade both flutter and dart SDK.
Actually `flutter upgrade` includes the Flutter and Dart SDK and doesn't install them separately.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

*or this*

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

if you using android studio,
Tools->Flutter->Flutter upgrade
click on flutter upgrade then you can install it

Answer (score 2):

follow some command given below :

1.**flutter --version** -> give all the flutter version list available.

2.**flutter version v1.12.13+hotfix.7** -> you can switch to any given flutter version
in your console by 1st command.

Comment: "flutter version" command does not exist. Did you mean: "flutter --version" instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
Open terminal commands to Upgrade Flutter – Dart SDK
1-> C:\flutter 
2->run command  " flutter channel master "
3->run command after switching " flutter upgrade "
```

[image]
Now open android studio which automatically fetch updated sdk from flutter folder

Answer (score 2):

The dark SDK that you updated is probably the one on your global dart installation.

Check your flutter dart path with the command

```
which flutter dart
```

If it is looking like this

```
[/path-to-flutter-sdk]/bin/flutter
/usr/local/bin/dart
```

you need to change it to use the one associated to flutter:

```
[/path-to-flutter-sdk]/bin/flutter
[/path-to-flutter-sdk]/bin/dart
```

---

To update it, you need to update your `$PATH` so `[/path-to-flutter-sdk]/bin/flutter` comes before `/usr/local/bin`.

---

Comment: Can you tell me how we set path variable for flutter dart in detail

Answer (score 1):

If using windows, you can use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) to upgrade sdk by using command.

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

If you want the latest pre-release version:

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk --pre
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the cause of the problem is inherent in the fact that Flutter does not use the dart present on your Local machine the Flutter sdk instead comes with the
latest compatible dart sdk shipped along with it.

When you run the command `flutter version` it prints the current flutter version and the current dart-sdk version shipped along with it. If you wish to use a later version of the dart sdk you'll have to upgrade your flutter sdk and if the specific dart-sdk version you want is not yet available for any branch in the stable channel I will suggest you switch to the master or dev channel and hopefully the latest release of those channels will support the required sdk constraint you need. But beware other branches aside the stable branch are not totally safe as you can encounter strange and unresolved errors so have that at the back of your mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `flutter upgrade channel stable` on macOS and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have two version of flutter SDK at the same time for two different flutter projects. I had changed the current SDK to 1.12 so it was complaining about dart SDK version. I changed the current version to 1.20 and the problem solved.

Comment: what is the command for upgrade2.14  2.16.0-40.0.dev

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle to make any of these solutions work, you might have different versions of flutter on your system.

I checked my version on the command line and upgraded via 'flutter upgrade' to the latest stable release, which did not solve the problem in IntelliJ / Android Studio, as that pointed to another local version of flutter.

To check, run 'which flutter' on the command line and check with the version displayed in "Preferences --> Languages & Frameworks --> Flutter" and make sure they point at the same flutter installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using "brew update dart" not working. If so you can go to the dart sdk path "/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk" and then remove dart-sdk and install a new stable version the paste it there. you can check the new verion by writing
"dart --version" on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First change the Flutter to stable by `flutter channel stable` then try upgrading the flutter by `flutter upgrade`

It worked... just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your separate `dart-sdk` path from environment variable (the path outside flutter folder). Because of two paths VSCode use older dart version. And don't forget to reload IDE and terminal. Worked for me on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the following command

```
flutter upgrade
```

If you face any issues, do this instead

```
flutter upgrade --force
```