# Dart 2.3 for, if and spread support warning message regarding versions

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting the warning message '**The for, if and spread elements were not supported until version 2.2.2, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions**' but the code

```
Column(   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              if (document['propertyid'] == '1') Text('jjj'),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              PropertyDetails(document['propertyid'])));
                },
                child: Text(document['propertyname'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight
                            .w500) //Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    ),
              ),
            ],
  ),
```

works as expected. The minSDKVersion etc is 28. Why does it think I want to be able to run this code on any earlier version? What do I need to change to a later version?

Comment: It is the day sdk that need to be constrained. See the pubspec file

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In `pubspec.yaml` you can update your environment sdk to get rid of those warnings:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: I had to use '>=2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5 <3.0.0' but that did solve the problem

Comment: just use environment:  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0" so you don't have to deal with Flutter's unconventional hotfix naming

Answer (score 4):

Press `option + return` on the warning and select `Update the SDK constraints`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SDK to `">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"`resulted in another issue.

[image]

However `">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"` works like a charm!