# The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.4. how can I change the version into a upper version .? In a beta or dev channel

Tags: flutter, dart

Because classbe depends on cupertino_icons >=1.0.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in classbe... pub get failed (1; Because classbe depends on cupertino_icons >=1.0.1 which requires SDK version >

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908425/11675817

Comment: Change the environment file in pubspec to suit you. Sometimes works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [update dart sdk for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898181/update-dart-sdk-for-flutter)

Answer (score 26):

Update your **pubspec.yaml** depending on the flutter channel you want to work on:

If you are on `stable` channel :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.5 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
```

If you are on `beta` channel :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
```

Then if you are on stable channel (or beta),

```sh
flutter channel stable
# or flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 12):

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Just 'flutter upgrade' worked for me, thanks

Comment: Of course it would work for you if you were already on the beta branch, or if the stable branch had advanced beyond the desired version.  But that's not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to run a simple command from your terminal

> flutter upgrade

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33135411)

Comment: This is the right answer for the general question. If you get a "The current Dart SDK version is X" error, then try this as a first step.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It simply does the work done.

Answer (score 2):

If you work on Windows do the following:

**Open PowerShell as Admin** use

```
choco install dart-sdk
```

**or to upgrade**

```
choco upgrade dart-sdk
```

By default, the SDK is installed at **C:\tools\dart-sdk**

Than go to your IDE and **check the location of your Dart SDK**.
For **Intellij** use

**File**->**Settings**->**Language & Framework**->**Dart**->**Dart SDK path**

Her paste **C:\tools\dart-sdk** (by default)

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade your flutter
With command line:

```
flutter upgrade -v
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was different, i had changed my flutter and dart version in android studio but it was not reflecting in vs code, what I did was

1. I open a flutter file
2. at the bottom of vscode, there is a place were {} Dart is written I clicked on it and then it open up the the command palette, so I clicked on "Configure Dart language based setting"
3. This then open the dart configuration and I changed "dart.flutterSdkPath" to the path where my current SDK and it fixed the problem.

You can also use this for the above just download the flutter SDK you want to use to a location and follow the step I stated above

Answer (score -1):

pubspack requirement of dart sdk to a lower vs ... like mine was and dart sdk was 3.0.*
environment:
sdk: '>=3.1.0-163.1.beta <4.0.0'

I changed to
environment:
sdk: '>=3.0.0-163.1.beta <4.0.0'

It's a quick dirty temporary fix until next update ... You should know changing requirement on .pubspac can have effect on the project.

Answer (score -2):

The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.2.

Because news depends on http >=1.0.0 which requires SDK version ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34461042)