# How to change the current Dart SDK version?

Tags: flutter, dart

I ran the following commands in my `foo` project:

```
iDecode@iDecodes-Mac foo % pub get
Resolving dependencies... 
The current Dart SDK version is 2.7.2.

Because foo requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
iDecode@iDecodes-Mac foo % flutter --version
Flutter 2.6.0-11.0.pre • channel dev
Tools • Dart 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-116.0.dev)
```

My `pubspec.yaml` file has:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

As you can see my current Dart SDK version is set to `2.7.2`, my project is targeting a min of `2.12.0` and Dart SDK installed on my machine is `2.15.0`. So, how do I change the current Dart SDK version?

This is my `~/.zshrc` file

```
export PATH=/flutter/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
export PATH="$PATH:/$HOME/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Comment: Does `dart pub get` or `flutter pub get` make a difference?  Most of the Dart commands now should be invoked through `dart` (or `flutter`), so you might be running an old `pub` binary.

Comment: @jamesdlin But when I run `dart pub get`, it gives me this nice error "Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory". However, `flutter pub get` works.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've also added the Dart SDK environment variable in my `~/.zshrc` file. `dart --version` prints `Dart VM version: 2.7.2`. So, I think there's something wrong which I'm not aware of.

Comment: You have a separate installation of the Dart 2.7.2 SDK in your `PATH`.  You probably should remove it and just use the Dart SDK that comes with the Flutter SDK.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've included all `PATH`s I have set.

Comment: You have both `/flutter/bin` and `$HOME/flutter/bin` in your `$PATH`, and hence you have two Flutter SDKs installed with two different versions.  Remove one of them.

Comment: @jamesdlin I previously installed Flutter in `/flutter/bin` but it is no longer a folder in my Finder and I've also removed this line from `~/.zshrc` file however I'm still getting the same outputs for my command. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: 1. Where is the old version of `pub` coming from? (Run `which pub`.) 2. Where are you running the `dart` binary from? (Run `which dart`.) 3. Search your system for all `dart` binaries.

Comment: @jamesdlin 1. `which pub` prints `/usr/local/bin/pub`. 2. `which dart` prints `/usr/local/bin/dart`. 3. Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: You have a separate (and old) Dart installation in `/usr/local/bin`, maybe from Homebrew or something.  Uninstall that (or update it).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for pointing out the issue, and sorry for this stupid question but can I directly delete `bin` and `dart` file from it or should I run a proper Homebrew command?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems like you installed Flutter/Dart SDK somewhere using Homebrew. Use `which flutter` and `which dart` to see the actual Flutter/Dart command that is taking effect. Once you find where your Dart SDK is you can use

```
brew uninstall dart
```

After this when you run `which dart` it will now point to where your Flutter SDK was installed.

Comment: Yes, `which flutter` and `which dart` points to different location `/usr/local/bin/dart` It seems like I installed the Dart SDK separately (when it didn't use to come preinstalled with Flutter SDK). But I don't know how to delete that `Dart` SDK, I can only see `dart` as a file not a directory.

Comment: @iDecode you should find out how you installed it, then you can uninstall. For example, maybe you have used homebrew?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, now I remember that I used homebrew to install Dart, using `brew uninstall dart` removed the SDK and now it's all working good.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade by running `flutter upgrade` [check it out here] ([update dart sdk for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898181/update-dart-sdk-for-flutter))

Comment: I already did that before posting the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this way:
Just download that specific flutter version from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases). and just set the flutter version in your editor and try to run it will run that specific flutter version but make sure you can't run that with terminal commands. So you need to handle all commands from the Tools option.

[set flutter version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqnMR.png)

[Must Run commands from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hKR.png)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but unfortunately it's not something that is easy to do.

Comment: please check my answer again I change the image in the set flutter version. It's the simplest way to change the flutter & dart version. you need to just set the flutter folder path after that dart part will automatically set. but when you set up flutter like this then you need always apple command from the tools option only.

Answer (score 2):

The `dart` version is related with `flutter` version, see which version is what you need here

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

Answer (score 1):

Flutter comes with dart by default. Suggestion is to delete old flutter, delete .zshrc and download the latest stable version 2.5.3 for your mac and then give path for it in your .zshrc. Other method is switch to flutter stable by running flutter channel stable and then give flutter upgrade command so it will catch all the stuff from git in you local machine and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I've fresh install flutter in my mac with new OS Monterey everything is super fine dart and flutter both up-to date running.

Comment: How can I delete old Flutter? `which dart ` points to `/usr/local/bin/dart` file and `which flutter` to `home/flutter/bin/flutter`

Comment: Delete the SDK folders what which command is referring to. Not sure about dart is in bin/dart so take a look at dart directory to see if there is no system files in that if not then delete it and delete whole flutter folder that's all make sure .zshrc is also deleted there's no path given, restart once and install flutter again

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the location where Dart SDK is kept and delete that and install a new Dart SDK version from the official website which is

`https://dart.dev/get-dart`

Comment: Thanks, actually I have two Dart SDK installed on my machine, the one which was installed manually using `HomeBrew` and the other which came preinstalled with Flutter. The manual one was outdated and creating issues. I deleted that using `brew uninstall dart` and now I only have the Dart SDK which came preinstalled with Flutter :)

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue

Resolving dependencies... (5.3s)
The current `Dart SDK` version is `2.17.0`.

Because `talk_to_me` depends on `browser >=0.3.1+1` which requires SDK version
<2.0.0, version solving failed
I think we need to uninstall dart and install the correct version

To uninstall dart:

`sudo apt purge dart`