# How can I change the Dart SDK version with FVM in my Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

I was running an old project and using FVM to change the flutter sdk version.

It changes flutter's SDK version but not the Dart SDK version which leads to some error.
How can I set dart SDK version to any desired version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608798/how-to-change-the-current-dart-sdk-version

Answer (score 1):

As of fvm 2.4.1, you still cannot install the dart sdk separately from the flutter sdk. And it also means that you can't select the dart sdk version.

The only solution at the moment is that you can find the right version of the dart sdk by installing a suitable version of the flutter sdk