# updating flutter sdk cause an issue with firebase_core, firebase_auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because new_flutter_app depends on firebase_core >=1.13.0 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because new_flutter_app depends on firebase_core >=1.13.0 which requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

note- when i print dart version  it print 2.17.0

i use this command but nothing changed or fixed
flutter upgrade

Comment: You can search for the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898181/update-dart-sdk-for-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit the package pages and try each version that fits your dependencies

> firebase_core -> https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/versions
>
> firebase_auth -> https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/versions

I don't know is there any other version but basically upgrade each version one by one to find suitable versions that dependent each other.

Hope it helps!