In flutter terminal when i try to run flutter pub get it is not working properly
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0-146.2.beta.
Because flutter_fire_base_2 requires SDK version >=3.4.3 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_fire_base_2...
pub get failed
command: "C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --verbosity=warning get --no-precompile"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1
last line of pub output: "Because flutter_fire_base_2 requires SDK version >=3.4.3 <4.0.0, version solving failed."

Update first dart version.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66316520/13973724

Actually you should give more info about your error like screenshot when you run

flutter doctor -v || flutter --version

Im not sure about your issues If im not understand wrong you can try to change your sdk version to 3.22.2 or newer that use dart version 3.4.3

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive

and then update your pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

